# What is a good book that focuses on the applications of complex analysis and spectral theory?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

My research involves a great deal of complex analysis and spectral theory, and I always feel a bit flustered when non mathematicians ask me what I study. It's hard to explain the math in layman's terms. I was thinking that, instead of explaining the math, I could explain some applications of my areas, and that would be much more entertaining and accessible. For complex analysis, I explain the applications of the poisson integral formula by saying "if you know the temperature of a metal disk at its edges, you can recover its temperature at any point." I'm at a loss for anything else because my education is in pure mathematics.

Comment: I could recommend areas but no specific book that covers them all.  Generally speaking, it seems most applications come from the usual suspect in the human approach to complicated problems: Decompose complicated problems into the fundamental pieces and hope that we can understand the fundamental parts.